# Creating a trajectory function for determining the which areas on the line will be effecting or not?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

Hi I have been trying to solve a question about four hours and it started to does not make sense.

[image]

Although the question looks complicated. I figured out that we must find the `dry` and `wet` connection point. I will call this points `min_wet` and `max_wet`. I think we can assume that for getting `min_wet`, our ball draw a `tangent` line at the `(1,1)` point. So I wrote the trajectory formula.

> y = x * tan(O) - (g*x^2)/(2 * u^2 * cos^2(O)) 
> u = initial speed which is square root of 50 
> g = gravity which equals 10

The problem here is when I plug in (1,1) I have encountered with

```
10cos^2(O) = sin(O)cos(O) - 1 which has no solution.
```

What is the problem with my reasoning?
Can You solve this equation?

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you did seems to be perfectly fine except for a single point: When you multiply
$$
\cos^2(O) = \sin(O) \cos(O) - \underbrace{\frac{g}{2u^2}}_{=1/10}
$$
with 10, you have to multiply *all* terms with 10, which yields
$$
10\cos^2(O) = 10 \sin(O) \cos(O) - 1~.
$$
This equation should have a (in fact several) solution.

Comment: Yes, but only two roots in the range $\:[0,π/2]\:$. Also note that  the function $\:f(\phi)\boldsymbol=10\cos^2(\phi)\boldsymbol-10 \sin(\phi) \cos(\phi)\boldsymbol+1\:$ is periodic with period $\:\pi$.

Comment: Your trigonometric equation could be solved analyticaly since it could be transformed to
$$
\cos2\phi\boldsymbol-\sin2\phi\boldsymbol{=-}\dfrac{6}{5}\quad\boldsymbol\implies\quad \cos\left(2\phi\boldsymbol+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right) \boldsymbol{=-}\dfrac{3\sqrt{2}}{5}
$$

Comment: how did you come up cos2ϕ−sin2ϕ=−6/5?

Comment: @asimtot :  
$$
\cos^2\phi\boldsymbol=\dfrac{1\boldsymbol+\cos2\phi}{2}\,, \qquad 2 \sin\phi \cos\phi\boldsymbol=\sin2\phi
$$